# Is there any other reason to put these P.Oxy. 1787 frr. 1&2 together than Athenaeus's quotation? And what about the little Cologne scrap?

Tags: greek, poetry, text-corpus, sappho

I researched the sources of Sappho's `῎Υμμες πεδὰ Μοίσαν ἰοκόλπων κάλα δῶρα παῖδες` (whatever the number is). There are two scraps from P.Oxy. 1787, precisely frr. 1-2, and potentially fr. 2(a), with very low certainty; then we have a quotation by Athenaeus's Deipnosophistae; finally, we have [three papyrus scraps](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyrhynchus_papyri#/media/File:P.K%C3%B6ln_XI_429.jpg) (feels weird to call those two big ones "scraps" though) conserved in Cologne. Now let's see why these are placed together:

- The medium-sized fragment from Cologne and the P.Oxy. fr. 1 overlap for 4 consecutive lines;
- The big Cologne fragment overlaps with P.Oxy. fr. 1 for a whole lot of lines;
- P.Oxy. fr. 2 starts with `τολα`, which is recognizable from Athenaeus's quotation as the start of the last line of P.Oxy. fr. 1;
- To put the P.Oxy. fragments together, we also have Grenfell-Hunt's note, which I fail to understand and will discuss below: «That the small fragment containing the beginnings of ll. 25-9 is rightly placed can hardly be doubted. The fact that l. 28 is the last of a column helps to confirm the coincidence of the letters `τολα[` in l. 25.»;
- I can't seem to find any valid reason for the little Cologne fragment to go with the others, other than that it is in the picture with the other two Cologne fragments;
- The reason for putting fr. 2.(a) in this as well is «the similarity on both sides to the upper part of fr. 1».

I guess the reason to assume l. 28 (last line of fr. 2) is the last of a column is that the line below in the fragment appears blank. If there were another line below it, it should extend to below the letters we have of those above. However, how does this support the thesis that 1) they are the starts of lines (and not the middles or ends e.g.) and 2) they belong with fr. 1 with the first line of fr. 2 being the last of fr. 1?

Is there any reason for the little Cologne fragment to belong to this poem?

And is there a scan of fr. 2.(a) so that I can see the mentioned *similarity on both sides to the upper part of fr. 1*, which now appears as an unverifiable claim to me?